# Angular REST get using ngresource

Tags: c#, javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I need to consume a Json WebService from angular.

I wrote a web service in C# that implements a REST api and return json objects.

Following this tutorial 
(http://www.masnun.com/2013/08/28/rest-access-in-angularjs-using-ngresource.html ) that implements exactly what I would perform:

```
/* Controllers.js */
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('my.controllers', []);

app.controller( 'UserListCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function myController($scope, $userFactory) {
    $scope.user= $userFactory.query({},{'Id':1});
}]);



/* Service.js */
var service = angular.module('ngdemo.services', ["ngResource"]);
// Booking Resource
service.factory("User", function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        "http://192.168.1.147:port/ServizioWeb/rest/user/:Id", 
        { port : ':8002', Id: "@Id" },
        {
            "update": {method: "PUT"},
            "reviews": {'method': 'GET', 'params': {'reviews_only': "true"}, isArray: true}

        }
    );
});
```

Writing the url address in a browser the json get the  expected results

```
 eg. *http://192.168.1.147:8002/ServizioWeb/rest/user/1* 

{"FirstName":"Leo","Id":1,"LastName":"Messi"}
```

Attemping with angular i didn't receive any answer.

[image]

Any help or hint is really appreciated!

Comment: You need to enable CORS on your web service.

Comment: I agree with @AnthonyChu, enabling CORS should do the trick, please tell us which version of webapi you used.

Comment: I'm using WCF in .net 4.0 with a standalone C# implementation. Probably you are right, actually I don't manage CORS.